# How do I convert something of kind [13H1,13H2,14H1,14H2] into datetime format?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

How do I convert Half year's into datetime format so that I could use it for time series forecasting to predict next Half's sales?

```
13H2    2212.06
14H1    1031.40
14H2    665.68
15H1    11482.03
15H2    672.10
16H1    1807.82
16H2    11686.32
17H1    26580.62
17H2    37328.25
```

Comment: What is expected output from sample data?

Comment: convert the first column into datetime format. while the second column is the amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not totally clear to me what is your desired output, maybe you could try in this way:

```
d = {'H1':'-30-06', 'H2':'-31-12'}
df['date'] = df['date'].replace(d, regex=True)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y-%d-%m')
```

Where the dictionary `d` is set to have the values at the end of half year.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank You.

Comment: Glad I could help!